# The distribution of a complex signal

Tags: normal-distribution, signal-processing

If I have a complex signal
$$ y = h e^{j\phi} + n $$
where $ h \sim \mathcal C \mathcal N (0, \sigma_h^2) $
and $ n \sim \mathcal C \mathcal N (0, \sigma_n^2) $.

With $ h = |h|e^{j\theta} = |h|\cos \theta + j|h|\sin \theta $  and  $ n = n_r + j n_i $,
I can rewrite $y$ as
$$ y = |h| e^{j(\phi+\theta)} + n $$
and thus the real part of $y$ should be
$$ y_r = |h| \cos(\phi + \theta) + n_r $$

Now my question is, how do I find the distribution (pdf) $ p(y_r; \theta)$ with these given information?
Should it be $ \mathcal N (0, \sigma_h^2 + \sigma_n^2) $
or $ \mathcal N (|h| \cos(\phi+\theta), \sigma_n^2)$ or anything else?

note:
1. $h$ and $n$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

(I am assuming $h$, $\phi$ and $n$ are independent.)

Note that a complex Gaussian random variable $x\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2)$ is *circularly symmetric*, i.e., for every $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi)$ the law (distribution) of $e^{i\theta}x$ is identical to the law of $x$. This is usually denoted as

$$
e^{i\theta}x \stackrel{d}{=}x,
$$

where $\stackrel{d}{=}$ means "equality in distribution".

It follows that

$$
\begin{align}
y &= e^{i \phi} h + n\\
&\stackrel{d}{=}h+n\\
\end{align}
$$

and the last sum is, of course, distributed as $\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma_h^2+\sigma_n^2)$. By fundamental properties of complex Gaussian random variables, the real and imaginary parts of $y$ are independent and distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0,(\sigma_h^2+\sigma_n^2)/2)$.

Comment: > The real and imaginary parts of $y$ are independent and distributed as $\mathcal{CN}(0,(\sigma_h^2+\sigma_n^2)/2)$. 
Should it be $\mathcal{N}(0,(\sigma_h^2+\sigma_n^2)/2)$ ?

Comment: @Julie Yes, thanks for catching this. Edited.

Comment: But then is it possible to represent it in a form containing $\theta$?

Comment: @Julie No. Rotating $h$ by an arbitrary complex exponential does not change its distribution (circular symmetry property). The exact value of $\theta$ does not affect the statistics.

Comment: I agree that $\theta$ doesn't affect the distribution of the complex variable $y$ due to the circular symmetry property of complex normal distribution. But what about the real part of $y$? The real part of $y$ should be $y_r = |h| \cos(\phi+\theta) + n_r$, where $n_r$ is the real part of $n$. As you mentioned, it is normal distributed. Then, may we represent the distribution of $y_r$ in a form containing $\theta$?
(Thanks for your answers.)

Comment: @Julie $\phi$ is distributed uniformly in $[-\pi,\pi)$, therefore, so is $\phi +\theta$ (no matter what $\theta$ is).

Comment: @Julie correction: $\theta$ and $\phi$ should be exchanged in my previous comment (sorry for any confusion)